# CSS Navigation drop-down issues

Tags: jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

Aright so there is a problem with my drop down. Its a single dropdown yet I am not having much luck with it. If I or user where to cover over the categories the bellow "ul" would be displayed along with its child "li" and "a" elements. However it does not work that way. Hover over categories does bring up the menu, but ones you try to move the mouse to the menu it hides.

**HTML Component**

```
<header role="header">
    <div class="frame">
        <nav role="navigation" class="bit-1">
            <ul>
                <li> <a href="" class="brand">Tutor <span>Hive</span></a>

                </li>
                <li> <a href="#" class="cat">Categories</a>

                    <ul class="cat-drop">
                        <li> <a href="/cat/all">All Categories</a>
 <a href="/cat/math">Math</a>
 <a href="/cat/biology">Biology</a>
 <a href="/cat/sciences">Sciences</a>
 <a href="/cat/chemistry">Chemistry</a>
 <a href="/cat/physics">Physics</a>
 <a href="/cat/business">Business</a>
 <a href="/cat/health">Health & Medicine</a>
 <a href="/cat/english">English</a>
 <a href="/cat/french">French</a>
 <a href="/cat/foreign">Foreign Languages</a>
 <a href="/cat/esl">ESL</a>
 <a href="/cat/literacy">Reading & Writing</a>
 <a href="/cat/computers">Computers</a>
 <a href="/cat/arts">Visual Arts</a>
 <a href="/cat/sports">Sports & Couching</a>
 <a href="/cat/preschool">Pre-school Education</a>
 <a href="/cat/music">Music</a>
 <a href="/cat/disability">Learning Disabilities</a>
 <a href="/cat/social">Social Studies</a>
 <a href="/cat/psychology">Psychology</a>
 <a href="/cat/religion">Religion</a>

                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <div class="right_menu">
                    <li> <a href="#region">Brampton</a>

                    </li>
                    <li class="sep"></li>
                    <li> <a href="#signin">Sign in</a>

                    </li>
                    <li> <a href="#signup" class="btn btn-signup">Sign up</a>

                    </li>
                </div>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>
```

**CSS Component**

```
header {
    background: #fefefe;
    padding: 16px 80px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65);
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 10000;
    display: block;
}
nav {
    padding: 20px 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 400;
    letter-spacing: 0.06em;
    display: block;
}
nav > ul {
    margin: 18px 0;
    list-style: none;
}
nav > ul > li {
    display: inline-block;
}
nav > ul ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
}
nav ul:after {
    content:"";
    clear: both;
    display: block;
}
nav > ul > li:hover > ul {
    display: inline;
    background: transparent;
    padding: 0px 80px;
}
nav > ul > li:hover > a.cat {
    background: #F77036;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #DD6430;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 3px;
    transition: all 400ms;
}
nav > ul ul > li {
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 16px 4px;
    min-width: 400px;
    display: block;
}
nav > ul ul > li > a {
    color: #313131;
    background: #fff;
    border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
    padding: 15px 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
}
nav > ul ul > li > a:hover {
    background: #4b545f;
}
nav > ul > li > a, .right_menu > li > a {
    color: #313131;
    background: none;
    border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
    padding: 15px 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: 3px;
    transition: all 400ms;
    outline: none;
}
nav > ul > li > a:hover, .right_menu > li > a:hover {
    background: #F77036;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #DD6430;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 3px;
    transition: all 400ms;
}
nav > ul > li > a.active, .right_menu > li > a.active {
    color: #fff !important;
    font-weight: 600;
}
nav > ul > li > a.brand {
    background: #CF4920;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #BA411C;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 15px 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: 3px;
    transition: all 400ms;
    outline: none;
    text-align: center;
}
nav > ul > li > a.brand:hover {
    opacity: 0.8;
    transition: all 400ms;
}
nav > ul > li > a.brand > span {
    color: #fff;
    border-left: 1px solid #fff;
    padding: 0 4px;
    font-family:'Permanent Marker', cursive;
    font-weight: normal;
}
/* Navigation Right Menu */
 nav > ul > .right_menu {
    float: right;
}
nav > ul > .right_menu > li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
}
nav > ul > .right_menu > li > a.btn-signup {
    background: #A3D29C;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #91BB8B;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 3px;
    transition: all 200ms;
}
nav > ul > .right_menu > li > a.btn-signup:hover {
    opacity: 0.8;
    transition: all 200ms;
}
nav > ul > .right_menu > li.sep {
    border-left: 1px solid #ddd;
    width: 1px;
    margin: -12px 2px;
    padding: 16px 0;
}
```

Here is a JS Fiddle for the script: http://jsfiddle.net/xrjN2/2/
And full-preview: http://jsfiddle.net/xrjN2/2/embedded/result/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the fiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/6LSVh/) with below corrected css.

```
header {
    background: #fefefe;
    padding: 16px 80px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65);
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 10000;
    display: block;
}
nav {
    padding: 20px 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 400;
    letter-spacing: 0.06em;
    display: block;
}
nav ul {
    margin:18px 0;
    list-style: none;
}
nav ul li {
    float:left;
    margin-right:5px;
    /*position:relative;*/
}
nav ul li a, 
.right_menu li a {
    color: #313131;
    background: none;
    border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
    padding: 15px 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: 3px;
    transition: all 400ms;
    outline: none;
    }

nav ul li a:hover, 
.right_menu li a:hover {
    background: #F77036;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #DD6430;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 3px;
    transition: all 400ms;
}
nav ul li:hover a.cat,
nav ul li.active a.cat {
    background: #F77036;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #DD6430;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 3px;
    transition: all 400ms;
}
nav ul li a.active, 
.right_menu li a.active {
    color: #fff !important;
    font-weight: 600;
}
nav ul li a.brand {
    background: #CF4920;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #BA411C;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 15px 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: 3px;
    transition: all 400ms;
    outline: none;
    text-align: center;
}
nav ul li a.brand:hover {
    opacity: 0.8;
    transition: all 400ms;
}
nav ul li a.brand span {
    color: #fff;
    border-left: 1px solid #fff;
    padding: 0 4px;
    font-family:'Permanent Marker', cursive;
    font-weight: normal;
}
/* Navigation Right Menu */
 nav ul .right_menu {
    float: right;
}
nav ul .right_menu li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
}
nav ul .right_menu li a.btn-signup {
    background: #A3D29C;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #91BB8B;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 3px;
    transition: all 200ms;
}
nav ul .right_menu li a.btn-signup:hover {
    opacity: 0.8;
    transition: all 200ms;
}
nav ul .right_menu li.sep {
    border-left: 1px solid #ddd;
    width: 1px;
    margin: -12px 2px;
    padding: 16px 0;
}

nav ul:after {
    content:"";
    clear: both;
    display: block;
}
/*----------------Drop menu starts----------------*/
nav ul li ul {
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    top:69px;
    left:0;
    background-color:#313131;
    width:100%;
    padding:15px;
}
nav ul li ul li a {
    color:#313131;
    background-color:#fff;
    border:0;
    border-radius:0px;
    transition: all 0ms;
    float:left;
    margin:0 5px 5px 0;
    }
nav ul li ul li a:hover {
    background:#4b545f;
    border:0;
    color: #313131;
    border-radius:0;
    transition: all 0ms;
}
nav ul li:hover ul {
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: Some additional info on what you corected and why would be good

Comment: I am not saying it would be good I just solve the issue of @MemeCat. It may be helpful for him/her  or mayn't be. Any way on what I corrected you want to know. Just follow the question correctly of MemeCat what he/she wants to say in his/her question. Then try to compare his/her css with my css.

Comment: @SwarnamayeeMallia thanks for help. From what you mostly did is remove OOCSS operators ">" and fixed a bit of my CSS. Its not quite what I needed, but eh. I will just rewrite the entire thing with a mega menu. See the original navigation wasn't written by me but by a friend of mine, and I simply tried to build on top. Failed at that.

Answer (score 0):

Only thing u can do is to bring the dropdown menu nearer to the MAIN MENU using  the css

```
 .cat-drop {
    margin-top: -50px;
 }
```

event hover should bind the drop down menu class also like this

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

 $(".cat .cat-drop").hover(

 function () {
     $(".cat-drop").show();
 },

 function () {
     $(".cat-drop").delay("400").hide();
 });

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xrjN2/3/

Comment: I know my CSS is prob the main problem here. But I can't figure out what it is that is causing this issue. Your solution is rather neat but it does not fix the initial problem, nor do I want margin-top: -50px; added.

Comment: It is because when the mouse comes out of .cat the menu will hide since you specified to hide it in the mouseout function. $(".cat-drop").delay("400").hide();

Comment: Again, playing with my CSS seems to fix it, if I get it properly. It does not look the way it should. So I am looking over my CSS which is causing the fault here, not the JS.